# Creating a dynamic header UI with React and Material UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, material-ui

Inside my header.jsx file i have:

```
// Default Import Statements go here
var Login = require(login.jsx)
const HeaderComponent = React.createClass({

  getInitialState () {
    return {
      loggedIn: false,
    };
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <Toolbar>
        <ToolbarGroup key={1} float="right">
          <Login />
        </ToolbarGroup>
      </Toolbar>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = HeaderComponent;
```

And inside my Login Component (login.jsx):

```
// Default Import Statements

var LoginDialog = React.createClass({

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Dialog
          title="Login"
          ref="loginDialog"
          autoScrollBodyContent = {true}
          onRequestClose={this._cancelTouchTap}
          open={this.state.open}>
          <form action="/login" method="post" autoComplete="off">
            <div>
              <TextField hintText="Email Field" ref = "email" />
            </div>
            <div>
              <TextField hintText="Password" type="password" ref = "password"/>
            </div>
            <div>
              <RaisedButton label="Submit" onTouchTap={this._submitTouchTap}/>
              <RaisedButton label="Cancel" onTouchTap={this._cancelTouchTap}/>
            </div>
          </form>
        </Dialog>

        <FlatButton label="Login" style={loginSpacing} primary={true} onTouchTap={this._handleTouchTap} />

      </div>
    );
  },

  _submitTouchTap: function(){
    var primaryEmail = this.refs.email.getValue();
    var password = this.refs.password.getValue();
    var data = {
      primaryEmail: primaryEmail,
      password: password
    };
    $.ajax({
      url: '/login',
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'post',
      data: data,
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        this.transitionTo('/login'); 
      }.bind(this)
    });
    this.refs.loginDialog.setState({open: false});
  },

  _cancelTouchTap: function(){
    this.refs.loginDialog.setState({open: false});
  },

  _handleTouchTap() {
    this.refs.loginDialog.setState({open: true});
  }
});
module.exports = LoginDialog;
```

I want to switch my header's `loggedIn` state to true once my ajax call returns success when a user logs in. However, I am not quite sure on how to pass data from a separate file (child login.jsx) into my parent file (header.jsx).  Does anyone know how I can accomplish this so I can create a Dynamic UI for the header?

Once a user is logged in the state for loggedIn in the header component should return true. Once that is true I will display a different header than the one currently shown.

Comment: You can use a callback passed from your parent component to your child component and send data as an argument of this callback. Right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a callback:

```
var Login = require(login.jsx)
const HeaderComponent = React.createClass({

  getInitialState () {
    return {
      loggedIn: false,
    };
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <Toolbar>
        <ToolbarGroup key={1} float="right">
          <Login onLoggedIn={this._handleLogIn}/>
        </ToolbarGroup>
      </Toolbar>
    );
  },
  _handleLogIn: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    this.setState({loggedIn: true});
  }
});

module.exports = HeaderComponent;

var LoginDialog = React.createClass({

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Dialog
          title="Login"
          ref="loginDialog"
          autoScrollBodyContent = {true}
          onRequestClose={this._cancelTouchTap}
          open={this.state.open}>
          <form action="/login" method="post" autoComplete="off">
            <div>
              <TextField hintText="Email Field" ref = "email" />
            </div>
            <div>
              <TextField hintText="Password" type="password" ref = "password"/>
            </div>
            <div>
              <RaisedButton label="Submit" onTouchTap={this._submitTouchTap}/>
              <RaisedButton label="Cancel" onTouchTap={this._cancelTouchTap}/>
            </div>
          </form>
        </Dialog>

        <FlatButton label="Login" style={loginSpacing} primary={true} onTouchTap={this._handleTouchTap} />

      </div>
    );
  },

  _submitTouchTap: function(){
    var primaryEmail = this.refs.email.getValue();
    var password = this.refs.password.getValue();
    var data = {
      primaryEmail: primaryEmail,
      password: password
    };
    $.ajax({
      url: '/login',
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'post',
      data: data,
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        this.props.onLoggedIn(data);
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        this.transitionTo('/login'); 
      }.bind(this)
    });
    this.refs.loginDialog.setState({open: false});
  },

  _cancelTouchTap: function(){
    this.refs.loginDialog.setState({open: false});
  },

  _handleTouchTap() {
    this.refs.loginDialog.setState({open: true});
  }
});
module.exports = LoginDialog;
```

Comment: yes but if they are in seperate files can i still use a callback?

Comment: Yes, there is no problem they are in different files.

Comment: cool thanks i think im getting it, do you by any chance know how I can make changes to the header component once the state for `loggedIn` is set to true? Basically how i can switch out the current contents of the `<Toolbar>` with other contents?

Comment: Every time you change your state the render function is called. So you since you have a boolean in your state you probably want to do some kind of conditional rendering. Look: https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/if-else-in-JSX.html